# How to plot data while it's being processed

Tags: python, plot, gnuplot

I'm in the process of converting a large (several GBs) bin file to csv format using Python so the resulting data can be plotted. I'm doing this conversion because the bin file is not in a format that a plotting tool/module could understand, so there needs to be some decoding/translation. Right now it seems like Gnuplot is the way to go for such large data size.

I'm wondering if instead of waiting for the whole file to finish converting and then running Gnuplot, is there a way to plot the data as it's being processed? Perhaps I could bypass the csv file altogether.

Everything I've read so far points to plotting a file with data, but I have not seen any ways of plotting/appending individual data points.

Comment: Could you provide a little clarity on a) the shape of the data when it is in `csv` form and b) the kind of plot that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The data gets converted to csv in a very simple format: it's just two columns of values, one for voltage and one for current. I would like to plot these both on the y-axis with x-axis as the sample count. I'm actually not sure what kind of plot would best be suitable. I certainly don't want to miss out on any samples because I need to see the extreme peaks and troughs of both voltage and current.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot the data as it is being processed, but there's a couple of issues that come along with it in terms of efficiency.

1. Gnuplot needs to do work each time to process your data
2. Gnuplot needs to wait for your operating system to paint your screen whenever it updates
3. Your program needs to wait for Gnuplot to do any of this in order to go to the next step

All of these will greatly impact the amount of time you spend waiting for your data. You could potentially have it run every `x` iterations (eg. every 5 iterations), but even this wouldn't give you much of a speed-up.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've thought a bit more about this and I suppose there's really no convincing reason that I must do both process and plot at the same time. I will spend some time making a fast-as-possible conversion script and then figure out how to plot it best in gnuplot.